# Drupal 7 export Excel cannot open the file

Tags: drupal-7

Using Drupal 7, I do an excel export of a webform report.
When I try to open the excel file, I get an error: "Excel cannot open the file myfile.xlsx because the file format of file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

I open the file in an editor and I see an xml file which specifies the row data fine.
Can someone explain to me why Drupal is building excel files as xml as you can see in:
modules/contrib/webform/includes/exporters/webform_exporter_excel_xlsx.inc

and what's causing it not to load in excel?

Answer (score 1):

MS Office docs are just zip files containing xml docs and resources like images. You can change the extension of an xlsx (or docx) file and open it to see what is inside. I'm assuming a simple xml file could define a simple Excel file.

I've had issues in the past opening xlsx files from Drupal modules (and other systems) and I found that I could almost always open them in LibreOffice. I don't know enough about the format of an Excel file to determine the reason, it just became my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to overwriting existing temp zip files. You can update the webform module to the latest version or [fix this single bug](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/commit/69043e66515529a84b2289a3a4cb04a38b43bcbf).